# Different elements for specific UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview

Recently I am using twitter official iphone app. I noticed their UITableViewCells have some elements like label, image view and button. But not all of the cells have the same elements, some cells  have a someone retweet label, but some cells don't. and some cell have images and some cell don't. So the question how they do it? Are they using multiple dynamic prototype cell?

Answer (score 0):

You can create multiple cells in your story board and assign them different identifier.

Now you can dequeue different cell base on your logic

```
if(SomeConditionIsSatisfied)
{
     cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell1"];
}
else
{
     cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell2"];
}
```

Comment: I know this. Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: I guess that is the most appropriate way to do achieve this thing.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple approach to achieve this.

1. Use different prototype cell.
2. Use same cell and manager your UI in cellForRowAtIndexPath. As in write conditions and tweek your UI accordingly.

Best we to do it is using a different prototype cell.